# Dynamically allocating a matrix using unique pointers

Tags: c++, matrix, unique-ptr

The exercise I'm trying to solve states that I should create a dynamically allocated matrix using unique pointers that permits the following operations:

1. Matrix a,b;
2. Matrix c(b);
3. Matrix d=a;
4. Matrix e= a + b;

So far I've tried implementing the matrix (excluding the addition) but I can't wrap my head around how I should implement unique pointers in this example.

```
class Matrix
{

public:
    vector<vector<int>> data;

    Matrix() {}

    Matrix(vector<vector<int>> matrix)
    {
        this->data=matrix;
    }


    Matrix (const Matrix& m2)
    {
        this->data=m2.data;

    }
    Matrix& operator= (const Matrix &m2)
    {
        this->data = m2.data;
        return *this;
    }

  void print()
    {
        vector< vector<int> >::iterator row;
        vector<int>::iterator col;
        for (row = data.begin(); row != data.end(); row++)
        {
            for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++)
            {
                cout<<*col<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }

} ;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int> > matrix(3);
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )
        matrix[i].resize(3);

    Matrix m(matrix);
    m.print();

    Matrix m2(m);
    m2.print();

    Matrix m3;
    m3=m2;
    m3.print();

}
```

Help is much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Square matrix? For a matrix of size `n`, just allocate `n*n` integers and store them in a unique_ptr. I.e. `data = std::make_unique<int[]>(n*n);`. You will also have to store the size, `size = n`. That goes in your main constructor, implement all the other operations from there.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to store the _data_ in a `unique_ptr` (If yes, why? `vector` seems to be better suited.) Or do you want to create unique_ptrs to `Matrix`, e.g. `std::unique_ptr<Matrix>`? If yes, please show us an example of what you tried and what failed.

Comment: Your assignment specifies unique pointers, but you are using vectors. This is most probably not what your instructor wants.

Answer (score 1):

The only practical problem with you solution is that you user a `vector` of `vector`s, which may be slightly inefficient because there's an extra level of indirection in accessing the inner `vector`.

Better is to allocate a single `vector` to store the whole matrix, so:

```
class Matrix
{    
public:
    vector<int> data;
    int width;

    Matrix(int w, int h) : data (w * h), width(w)
    {

    }

    int& elementAt(int x, int y)
    {
        // Offset the row with y * width, then in the row the xth element
        return data[y * width + x];
    }

    ...
```

Instead of a `vector` you could just allocate a block of memory, managing it in a `unique_ptr`::

```
class Matrix
{    
public:
    unique_ptr<int[]> data;
    int width;

    Matrix(int w, int h) 
     : data (new int[w * h]), width(w) // Allocate dynamic array in unique_ptr
    {
       // Initialize data to zero
    }

    int& elementAt(int x, int y)
    {
        // Offset the row with y * width, then in the row the xth element
        return data[y * width + x];
    }

    ...
```

But I have to wonder what the point is. I can't see any obvious efficiency difference. Both automatically deallocate memory.

Functionally, you've already got the extra step of having to zero the data (of course, you may not want this). Additionally, one thing you don't have is the total size of the data. `vector` stores its own size, but the array doesn't so you'd probably have to separately store `height` as well as width.

Plus vectors are just generally easier to program.

Comment: I only got it wrong to demonstrate how much safer the `vector` solution is ;)